# GameLoop with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, game, animation

I am creating a HTML game where you fight monsters and stuff and this is part of the game loop for dealing damage:

```
var hp = 1000000000;
var speed = 10;
var power = 5;   

var lastCalledTime;
var fps;

var GameLoop = function() {
    if(!lastCalledTime) {
           lastCalledTime = new Date().getTime();
           fps = 0;
           return;
    }
    delta = (new Date().getTime() - lastCalledTime)/1000;
    lastCalledTime = new Date().getTime();
    fps = 1/delta;

    hp = hp - (5 * speed * 0.1) / fps;
};

var animFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                null ;

if ( animFrame !== null ) {
    var recursiveAnim = function() {
        GameLoop();
        animFrame( recursiveAnim );
    };
    animFrame( recursiveAnim );
} else {
    setInterval( GameLoop, 33.33 );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u0k7tbv4/2/

**Power** is how much you deal with each attack and each level of speed gives 0.1 attack / second. With 5 Power and 10 Speed it should deal 5 damage every second and that seems to be the case in the fiddle.

But I'm not sure, I only used `requestAnimationFrame` because I heard `setInterval` is unstable and so it would be nice if someone could validate the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `var GameLoop = function() { ... };`, you could just define a function the "natural" way.  Calling it `gameLoop()` would respect capitalization conventions better.

You neglected to use the `var` keyword when defining `delta`, so it becomes a global variable.

The `GameLoop()` function sets `fps` as a side-effect.  If you don't actually need `fps` anywhere else, then it should be local.  Furthermore, if you don't need `fps`, then there is no point in setting it to the reciprocal of `delta`.

I don't see much harm in initializing `lastCalledTime` right away, to eliminate the one-time-use special case inside `GameLoop()` — even if you technically didn't call `GameLoop()` at the time.

Calling `getTime()` twice is ugly.  If might also cause a tiny bit of clock skew.

```
var lastCalledTime = new Date().getTime();

function gameLoop() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var delta = (now - lastCalledTime) / 1000;
    lastCalledTime = now;

    hp -= 0.5 * speed * delta;
};
```

Alternatively, if you would like `lastCalledTime` neatly tucked inside the `gameLoop()` function rather than dangling outside, you could write:

```
function gameLoop() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (!arguments.callee.lastCalledTime) {
        arguments.callee.lastCalledTime = now;
    }
    var delta = (now - arguments.callee.lastCalledTime) / 1000;
    arguments.callee.lastCalledTime = now;

    hp -= 0.5 * speed * delta;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**• Use Classes** : Most easy way to have a clean start is to build a class, and start adding properties (in the constructor) and methods (on the prototype).
I used the very common convention for private properties to have them prefixed with '_'  (expl : this._delta ).
Even if they won't be private (Javascript requires more work than Dart to have properties private), it is a good convention.

**• Don't use**

```
var time = (new Date().getTime());
```

Because you are creating an object + invoking a function when :

```
var time = Date.now();
```

Does the same job, just faster.

**• requestAnimationFrame :** I'm not sure you need the requestAnimationFrame stuff : It has been unprefixed since quite some time, and i doubt someone playing on his browser can have a > 2 years old version.
Anyway, it's better written like that :

```
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
  (function() {
      var w=windows, raf="RequestAnimationFrame";
      window.requestAnimationFrame = w['webkit'+raf] || w['moz'+raf] || 
                                     w['o'+raf]      || ['ms'+raf]   ;
  }());
}
```

So now the class.
Notice that when providing a method to, say, rAF, for instance with :

```
 requestAnimationFrame(this.someMethod);
```

The function that you will send will just be the plain method you wrote, it will loose its context ( this === undefined ).
To say 'hey, when i talk about this function, i mean it as a method of 'this'', you have to bind the function. Binding the function creates another function that i prefer to store once to avoid creating garbage.

• **refactored code :**

```
function Game ( initialHP, initialSpeed, initialPower ) {
   this.hp    = intialHP;
   this.speed = initialSpeed;
   this.power = initialPower;
   this._lastCallTime = 0;
   this._delta        = 0;
   this._boundRecursiveAnim = null;
}

Game.Prototype = {
   startGame : function() {  
        if (window.requestAnimationFrame) {
            this._boundRecursiveAnim = this._recursiveAnim.bind(this);
            this._lastCallTime = Date.now();
            this._recursiveAnim(); 
         }
        else  setInterval( this.gameLoop.bind(this), 33.33 );
   },
   _recursiveAnim : function() { 
        requestAnimationFrame(this._boundRecursiveAnim);
        this._gameLoop();
   },
   _gameLoop : function () {  
        var currentTime = Date.now();         
        this._delta = 1e-3*(currentTime - this._lastCallTime);
        this._lastCallTime = currentTime;

        this.hp = this.hp - this._delta *(this.speed );
   },      
   getFPS() : function() { return  ( 1/this._lastCallTime ); }
}
```

use with

```
 var myGame = new Game(1000000, 5, 5);
 myGame.startGame();
```